# Add Lombok to a Gradle project in Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, lombok, gradle-plugin

New to Gradle. I Apologize if this is a bad question.

I've been trying to start a plain Java8 Gradle project. Everything was great until I tried to add Lombok to my project.

My Intellij IDE has all the settings required for Lombok.

1. Lombok plugin installed and activated
2. Annotation processor is on

The IDE is handling the annotations perfectly. No errors showing, and the boilerplate is shown in the code structure.

However, when I try to build the project or run the main method using Intellij, the compiler complains that the boilerplate Lombok is supposed to generate doesn't exist.

Environment

```
186590cf4989:JokerJava$ gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-02-08 19:00:10 UTC
Revision:     f02764e074c32ee8851a4e1877dd1fea8ffb7183

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.3
Kotlin:       1.3.20
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          11.0.5 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.5+10-LTS)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64
```

Some error message below:

```
8:23:21 PM: Executing task 'build'...

> Task :generateLombokConfig UP-TO-DATE

> Task :compileJava FAILED
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
warning: You aren't using a compiler supported by lombok, so lombok will not work and has been disabled.
  Your processor is: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.IncrementalProcessingEnvironment
  Lombok supports: sun/apple javac 1.6, ECJ
workspace/tank/JokerJava/src/main/java/tictactoe/game/gui/TicTacToeButton.java:11: error: variable index not initialized in the default constructor
    private final int index;
                      ^
workspace/tank/JokerJava/src/main/java/tictactoe/game/TicTacToe.java:42: error: constructor TicTacToeButton in class TicTacToeButton cannot be applied to given types;
            buttons[i] = new TicTacToeButton(i);
                         ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
/workspace/tank/JokerJava/src/main/java/tictactoe/game/TicTacToe.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
            int index = buttonClicked.getIndex();
                                     ^
  symbol:   method getIndex()
  location: variable buttonClicked of type TicTacToeButton
/workspace/tank/JokerJava/src/main/java/tictactoe/game/TicTacToe.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
            update(opponentAction.getPlayer(), opponentAction.getIndex());
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getPlayer()
  location: variable opponentAction of type UserAction
/workspace/tank/JokerJava/src/main/java/tictactoe/game/TicTacToe.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
            update(opponentAction.getPlayer(), opponentAction.getIndex());
                                                             ^
  symbol:   method getIndex()
  location: variable opponentAction of type UserAction
Note: /workspace/tank/JokerJava/src/main/java/Client.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
5 errors
1 warning

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
8:23:22 PM: Task execution finished 'build'.
```

See below for my build.gradle config

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "5.0.0-rc2"
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried manually adding lombok (without the io.freefair.lombok)? See https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

Comment: However, it seems you are not the only one having this issue: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2336. So maybe it's a general problem.

Comment: I've tried adding it manually without using lombok plugin which didn't work either. I'm using java8 here so maybe it is a separate issue?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't want to use spring, head over to the spring Initializer at https://start.spring.io/ and choose Gradle and add the Lombok dependency. It'll create a build.gradle for you with Lombok in the appropriate configurations (including annotationProcessor)

Comment: Thanks you, @lance-java. Your tip is very useful and help me a lot with debugging. Apparently, lombok 1.18.10 is not compatible with java 1.8.0_231, which is likely the issue Jan Rieke pointed in the comment.